# reactive power for power meter test (load bank)

Tags: dummy-load

I want to test a power meter and I need to test both active and reactive power. I use a resistive load bank to test active power. Now I want to see power meter performance in reactive loads. For achieving this goal what should I have to do?
Do I have to use a capacitor or inductor to consume reactive power?
for a 5kw load, which values of elements I have to choose and how is the calculation formulas?

Comment: You need to chose a capacitor and/or inductor that has an impedance comparable to the resistor value you use for the real power test. Do you know how to calculate the impedance of these elements?

Comment: I will appreciate you if tell me how to calculate them

Comment: Try using your favorite internet search engine with the terms "impedance", "capacitor", and "inductor".

Comment: ok, thank you. After finding the formulas, I must select a capacitor or inductor that it's impedance is equal to my resistor, is it right?

Comment: It depends on what kind of test you want to run. You may want to combine a resistor and a capacitor or inductor to achieve a specific power factor and then verify that your power meter gives you correct readings.

Comment: And how about the capacitor voltage for using in the 3phase circuit? and where can I find more details about this